# Why doesn't CSS stylesheet work on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, bootstrap-4

I am beginner in webdev. I am working on a website for a massage therapist using bootstrap.
The problem is that my CSS style is not showing up on mobile device. Backgrounds and bootstrap navbar disappear. I used a PNG file for a big logo, what won't show on mobile too. I tried to use chrome on mobile.

This is the HTML page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="hu de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Massage for You</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <!--CSS Stylesheets-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Righteous&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--Scripts-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c79cd4e211.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--This script is the language toggler-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var arrLang = {
      "hungarian": {
        "aboutme": "Bemutatkozó",
        "massage": "Masszázs",
        "contact": "Foglalás",
        "citation": "A masszázsra fordított idő sohasem elvesztegetett.",
        "introductiontitle": "Bemutatkozás"
      },
      "german": {
        "aboutme": "Einführung",
        "massage": "Massagen",
        "contact": "Kontakt",
        "citation": "Die Zeit, die eine Massage dauert, ist niemals verschwendet.",
        "introductiontitle": "Vorstellung"
      }
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // The default language is German
      var lang = "hungarian";
      $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
      });
    });

    // get/set the selected language
    $(function() {
      $(".translate").click(function() {
        var lang = $(this).attr("id");

        $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
          $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Nav Bar: It has two functions. Switch between languages ​​and menu bar for each block of the page-->
  <div class="background1">
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark fixed-top flex-column flex-md-row bd-navbar">
      <div class="navbar-nav-scroll">
        <ul class="navbar-nav bd-navbar-nav fex-row">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="lang nav-link" key="aboutme" href="#about-me"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="lang nav-link" key="massage" href="#massage"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="lang nav-link" key="contact" href="#contact"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-md-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="translate nav-link" id="hungarian" href="#">HU</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="translate nav-link" id="german" href="#">DE</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container logocontainer">
      <div class="row align-self-center">
        <div class="col-md-auto">
          <img class="logo" src="IMG/massage4U-3K62CX-300dpi.png" alt="Massage for You">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="about-me">
    <h3 class="lang section-title" key="introductiontitle"></h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
      book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and morerecently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="background2">

  </div>
  <div class="background3">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the CSS stylesheet:

```
 body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fbf0f0;
}

/*Navbar section Styling navbar items and language switcher.*/
.navbar {
  background-color: #7c7575;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.navbar-image {
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar-image {
  width: 180px;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #fbf0f0;
}

/*Background properties. Parallax effect*/
.background1 {
background-image: url(../IMG/backgroundimg1.jpg);
min-height: 100%;
}

.background2 {
background-image: url(../IMG/backgroundimg2.jpg);
min-height: 800px;
}

.background3 {
  background-image: url(../IMG/backgroundimg3.jpg);
  min-height: 800px;
}

.background1, .background2, .background3 {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/*Turn off parallax on mobile devices*/
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  .background1, .background2, .background3 {
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}

.logocontainer {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

[The page appearing on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bezfV.jpg)

[The page appearing on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kyGZ.jpg)

Comment: Check the media query you have included

Comment: @media(max-width: 768px){.foo{....}}

Comment: I set media query as written, but it didn't solve the problem. It looks like css don't loading on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The reason was the ID-based URL protocol used by mobile browsers.
This content protocol doesn't work and doesn't load any additional files (css sheet).